# Spring AOP around transactional service

Tags: spring-aop, spring-transactions, javers

I have 2 tables `CONTRACT` and `LG_CONTRACT`. Eeach time a contract is updated I would like to store the changes within `LG_CONTRACT`.

**My AOP**

```java
    @Around(value = "execution(* id.co.somepackage.cofinjms.service.implement.ConverterImpl.signContract(id.co.somepackage.cofinjms.entity.Contract,net.somepackage.homerselect.contract.v3.ContractFullInfoRequest))")
    public Contract around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Contract contract = (Contract) joinPoint.getArgs()[0];
        ContractFullInfoRequest contractFullInfoRequest = (ContractFullInfoRequest) joinPoint.getArgs()[1];
        if (contract != null) {
            javers.commit(contract.getContractNumber(), contract);
        }
        Contract updatedContract = (Contract) joinPoint.proceed();
        if (contract != null) {
            javers.commit(contract.getContractNumber(), updatedContract);
            Set<LgContract> lgContractSet = new HashSet<>();
            Date date = new Date();
            List<Change> changes = javers.findChanges(QueryBuilder.byInstanceId(contract.getContractNumber(), Contract.class).build());
            for (Change change : changes) {
                if (change.getClass().equals(ValueChange.class)) {
                    ValueChange vc = (ValueChange) change;
                    String oldValue = vc.getLeft() == null ? null : vc.getLeft().toString();
                    LgContract lgContract = new LgContract();
                    lgContract.setContract(contract);
                    lgContract.setColumnName(vc.getPropertyName());
                    lgContract.setValueOld(oldValue);
                    lgContract.setValueNew(vc.getRight() != null ? vc.getRight().toString() : null);
                    lgContract.setDtimeCreated(date);
                    lgContract.setSystemEvent(contractFullInfoRequest.getSystemEvent().toString());
                    lgContractSet.add(lgContract);
                }
            }
            updatedContract.setLgContracts(lgContractSet);
        }
        return updatedContract;
    }
```

**the service**

```java
@Transactional
    public Contract saveContract(String message) throws ContractNotFoundException {
        ContractFullInfoRequest contractFullInfoRequest = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(message), ContractFullInfoRequest.class);
        Contract contract = contractFullInfoRepository.findOne(contractFullInfoRequest.getData().getContractCode());
        switch (contractFullInfoRequest.getSystemEvent()) {
            case CONTRACT_SIGN_SE:
                contract = converter.signContract(contract, contractFullInfoRequest);
                break;
            case CONTRACT_ACTIVATION_SE:
                if (contract != null)
                    contract = converter.logBslStatusChange(contract, contractFullInfoRequest);
                else
                    contract = converter.activateNewContract(contractFullInfoRequest);
                break;
            case CONTRACT_PAID_OFF_SE:
            case CONTRACT_FINISHING_AUTOMATICALLY_SE:
            case CONTRACT_CANCELLATION_SE:
            case CONTRACT_FER_EXECUTED_SE:
            case PARTIAL_EARLY_REPAYMENT_SE:
                if (contract != null)
                    converter.logBslStatusChange(contract, contractFullInfoRequest);
                else
                    throw new ContractNotFoundException("Contract In MsContract Not Found");
                break;
            case CONTRACT_SERVICE_CHANGE_SE:
                if (contract != null)
                    converter.convertServiceChange(contract, contractFullInfoRequest);
                else
                    throw new ContractNotFoundException("Contract In MsContract Not Found");
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotYetImplementedException();
        }
        return contract;
    }
```

The AOP works as following

1. Get existing contract (before update / signing takes place)
2. Commit the existing contract
3. Let the signContract service proceed and store updated contract in the `CONTRACT` table
4. Compare the contract before and after sign process takes place then store the changes within `LG_Contract` table

Most of the time this works, however I notice there are cases when the AOP is able to store changes, however the contract itself is not updated.

This is how the LG_CONTRACT looks when everything works as expected (status changes from S > N > A)

```
3900742668  bslStatus   S   N   06-MAR-19 10.17.07.967000000 AM CONTRACT_SIGN_SE
3900742668  bslStatus   N   A   07-MAR-19 06.04.24.963000000 PM ContractActivationSE
```

and when the signing process does not work as expected (status never set to N in CONTRACT table, but LG_CONTRACT knows when status is set to N)

```
3902643905  bslStatus   S   N   11-JUL-19 11.32.09.400000000 AM CONTRACT_SIGN_SE
3902643905  bslStatus   S   A   12-JUL-19 10.51.00.383000000 AM ContractActivationSE
```

I dont understand why **sometimes** the AOP is able to store the contract status change from S to N in `LG_CONTRACT` but its not reflected in the `CONTRACT` table.

Comment: Based on the description it seems the advice ordering is messing things up. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33509777/1910582) for detailed explanation and solution.

Comment: Are you saying the ordering caused `signContract` method to fail saving the `contract` object ?

Comment: Without knowing the complete internals it would only be guess, unless we have a MCVE / SSCCE. I'll suggest to give it (ordering) a try and let know the outcome so that we can then investigate further.

Comment: Your pointcut targets `signContract` but you show us `saveContract`. Difficult to reason about invisible code...